# Xerces Sax2 parser encoding problem

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I've got a Sax parser class which is used in Swing application and in web project deployed to a GlassFish.

The class parses xml files. It works perfectly in Netbeans IDE Swing application(in the IDE) and web project.

But when I Clean and Build swing app into a one .jar it doesn't recognize anymore symbols like ī, ķ, ļ, ā from xml file.

The same problem happens if I compile and run it through cmd.

Had the same problem in web project - sorted using Glassfish configuration.

The question is how to solve this problem in swing app?

here is a peace of code:

```
public void parseDocument(String filePath) {

    try {
        XMLReader xr = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        xr.setContentHandler(this);
                    InputSource is = new InputSource(new FileReader(filePath));
                    is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        xr.parse(is);

    }catch(SAXException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

No help from   setEncoding()  method.

Comment: In the command line, can you use the JVM that Netbean uses to run your jar? I have experiences problem where while one JVM runs my code fine, but the other does not due to the underlying XMLReader implementation. Peace!

Comment: Thanks Alvin you sent me to look for the solution in the right direction.

Comment: @sergej.art if you like the answer, don't forget to upvote it, and possibly even accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You have already answered your question, however the other way that you could deal with this is to explicitly set the conversion when you open the file.

```
public void parseDocument(String filePath) {
  try {
    XMLReader xr = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    xr.setContentHandler(this);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath);
    InputSource is = new InputSource(reader, "UTF-8");
    is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    xr.parse(is);
  }catch(SAXException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
  }catch (IOException ie) {
    ie.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The big difference between this, and your solution in the question is that we are using InputStreamReader on top of a FileInputStream. According to the javadoc for [FileReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html), it always opens the file in the "default character set", that is why your solution works, since you are changing the default character set. You can also explicitly say which character set you want to open the file in, but to do that you need to use the combination of InputStreamReader and FileInputStream.

Comment: @sergej.art if you like the answer, don't forget to upvote it, and possibly even accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

The problem was with JVM settings.

I added a new variable in Windows system variables:

```
Variable name:JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
Variable value: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: are you sure about `UTF8`? For me, it seems not correct. Maybe `UTF-8`?